# Spring does not pass data between views

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new to Spring MVC. I have problem regarding passing objects between views. I can pass object Flight from view "flight" to view "searchFlight" without problem. There should be no passing of any object from "searchFlight" to "bookFlight" as at this point I store needed info in static object outside of controller.

In "bookFlight" I load all the data from static object (not editable in view) and then I want to gather data in "bookFlight" and pass it to "performBook" view. Gathered data is also stored in other static object outside of controller. At this point in "performBook" I can refer to static object and display data stored in - but I can not save anything from "bookFlight" into my static object.

If I change static object to non-static (simply copy-paste flighSearch method with different metohd body) then I also can not collect data from form:form and save it in object or pass it to next view.

This is my controller. Everything in GlobalCache is public static. Every model object has setters and getters.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/flight", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView flightSearch(ModelMap model) {
    GlobalCache.flight=new Flight();
    GlobalCache.flightTime=GlobalCache.generateFlightTIme()+1;
    GlobalCache.flight.setTravelLength(GlobalCache.flightTime);
    return new ModelAndView("flightSearch","command",new Flight());

}

@RequestMapping(value="searchFlight", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String search(@ModelAttribute("user") Flight flight, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("departureDate",flight.getDepartureDate());
    model.addAttribute("departureAirport",flight.getArrivalAirport());
    model.addAttribute("arrivalDate", flight.getArrivalDate());
    model.addAttribute("arrivalAirport", flight.getArrivalAirport());
    model.addAttribute("ticketNo", flight.getTicketNo());
    model.addAttribute("travelType", flight.getTravelType());
    model.addAttribute("flight", flight);

    GlobalCache.flight=flight;
    GlobalCache.flightTime=GlobalCache.generateFlightTIme()+1;
    GlobalCache.flight.setTravelLength(GlobalCache.flightTime);

    return "results";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/bookFlight", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView bookFLight(@ModelAttribute("user") Ticket ticket, ModelMap model) {

    ticket=new Ticket();
    ticket.setClassesList(classes);
    ticket.setPaymentTypeList(paymentType);
    ticket.setSeatPositionList(seatPosition);
    ticket.setFlight(GlobalCache.flight);
    ticket.setPayment(new Payment());
    ticket.setUtil(new Util());
    ticket.getPayment().setAmountToPay(GlobalCache.generateTicketCost());

    Traveler traveler = new Traveler();
    ticket.setTraveler(traveler);

    model.addAttribute("ticket", ticket);
    model.addAttribute("flight", GlobalCache.flight);
    model.addAttribute("traveler", ticket.getTraveler());
    model.addAttribute("payment", ticket.getPayment());

    GlobalCache.ticket=ticket;

    return new ModelAndView("book","command",GlobalCache.ticket);
}

@RequestMapping(value="performBook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView booked(@ModelAttribute("user") Ticket ticket, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("ticket", GlobalCache.ticket);
    return new ModelAndView("booked","command",GlobalCache.ticket);
}
```

Example of handling form in "bookFlight" view.

```
 <form:input path="traveler.name" value="${traveler.name}" type="text" id="5" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
```

Class structure:

```
class Ticket{
  private Flight flight;
  private Traveler traveler;
  private Util util;
  //getters and setters and other attributes
}
```

At this time I do not have time to create separate controllers, hope it can be solved with just one.